# What can we infer if the commutator subgroup $G'$ of a group $G$ is equal to $G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know that if the commutator subgroup $G'$ of a group $G$ is equal to $\{1\}$ then $G$ is abelian.  I think that if $G' = G$ then for all $a,b$ in $G$ with $a$ and $b$ not equal to the identity $ab$ is not equal to $ba$.  Right?
If $G$ is the alternating group on $5$ letters then $G' = G$.  Is this the smallest group with this property?
What else (that a beginning student in group theory might understand) can we conclude about groups with this property?

Comment: No clue, although if the group is simple then that holds. Also, if the group has a subgroup of index 2 that can't happen

Comment: It can't have a normal subgroup of prime index for similar reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are called [perfect groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group).  One important class of examples is the non-abelian simple groups, which are all perfect (because the commutator subgroup is normal).  But there are examples of perfect groups which are not simple.

Many things are known about perfect groups, some of which are accessible to beginners.  For example, we can show that any quotient of a perfect group is perfect, using the lattice isomorphism theorem.  In a similar fashion, we can show that a group is perfect if and only if, for any abelian group $A$ and homomorphism $f:G\to A$, we have $f(G) = \{e\}$ (equivalently, $G$ has no nontrivial abelian quotient).

You are correct that $A_5$ is the smallest non-trivial perfect group.

Your characterization is not correct: in general, we will have $ab=ba$ for many $a,b\in G$, even when $G=G'$, one simple example being $b=a$.

In $A_5$, here is a nontrivial counterexample: the permutations $(12)(34)$ and $(13)(24)$ commute.